# unknown app installs after app store submission of app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

This is the second time I am experiencing this and I find it bizarre. After I submit my app to App Store (in 30 minutes after submission), which is long before Apple start reviewing them, my app gets downloads (approximately 20).

I am collecting this data by server-side implementation of my app, and for that, as we know, app needs to be opened once.

Does anybody know anything about what this is?

**Note**: I know this is not programming-related question but I consider this relevant for coding and might be something important we should be aware of, that's why I am asking it here.

**Note 2**: My first thought was distribution of my binary throughout apple's servers. But the fact that my server side is being notified by installs is that app needs to be opened at least one time, which in my opinion, eliminates this option.

Comment: Are you sure it's not you running the app or your testflight users? I have never experienced this. Can you get the users location? Usually I only ever see about 5 sessions from cupertino during the review process.

Comment: im not registering for test flight, ip addresses are located on us, no host name identified...

Comment: It can be an automated download and run test...

Comment: May be related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145361/how-to-prevent-spike-in-flurry-user-activity-every-time-a-new-version-is-pushed